# HTML slideshow works but unable to control which images cycle

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I have an html slideshow which I got off of CodePen. It's called Vanilla JS Slideshow w/ CSS fade transition.

It works perfectly when alone, however on my homepage it cycles thru all images on that page.  The images are controlled by a small Javascript function centered around the following call.

```
var current = 0,
slides =
document.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

I want to be able to select only certain images to undergo the slideshow on the page.  Other images, such as the company logo, should not be flickering.

I've tried setting the slideshow images in a certain class as using that in my javascript function but my knowledge of Javascript variables is inadequate.

From the CodePen, note that image "Sheen" is missing in the original.

HTML

```
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/400/300" alt="Fill Murray">
<img src="http://www.placecage.com/400/300" alt="Place Cage">
<img src="http://www.placesheen.com/400/300" alt="Place Sheen">
```

CSS

```
img {
position: absolute;
transition: opacity 2.5s ease-in;
}
img + img { opacity: 0.95; }
```

Javascript

```
var current = 0,
slides = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
setInterval(function() {
for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
}
current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0;
slides[current].style.opacity = 1;
}, 5000);
```

You can see my working stand alone testing page here
https://flowsimulations.com/y_testing/slideshow_codepen_v1.html

I just can't get only a subgroup of the images to be in the slideshow. I won't show an example of this as I dont want to mess up my homepage but I can make another test page if desired showing the bad effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to all the img elements you want to include in your slideshow. Let's say you add "slideshow-image" to all your img elements. Then, in your javascript code, replace `document.getElementsByTagName("img")` with `document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow-image")`. It should work just fine.

Codepen with example [here](https://codepen.io/evelyng/pen/mdddzEb).

Comment: Yeah it works!   Thanks very much.  I also appreciate that you used the image class  "slideshow-image".  That way I knew it was your variable tag rather than some reserved variable and I could call it anything as long as I was consistant in naming thru my Html and Javascript.    If there were any books or classes on Javascript you could recommend, I'll look into them.

Comment: Glad I could help! I haven't tried the Javascript one but I usually like w3school's classes, they have you take little code "tests" to immediately practice after each lesson and they are easy to break down.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not absolutely sure how you tried it with classes, but that is the right way forward:

```
<img class="slide" src="something.png" alt="some description" />
```

Then you can select them accordingly in JS:

```
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('img.slide');
```

Comment: I'm not too good on Javascript variables; namely where to use the ' or the " to stick stuff together.  Notheless I'm going to try your solution also.  Evelyng's answer above worked: at least locally and on a test page.

Comment: This ALSO works.  Both yours & evelyng's: locally & online.  I used your var slides =  document.querySelectorAll('img.sliding') and adjusted my Html to    <img class="sliding" src="../images/revolving-test/Fill-murray_400x300.jpg" alt="Fill Murray">    and it works nicely.  Thanks very much!